# コメントで行末にスペースを2個入れても改行が追加されない

Tags: バグ, 仕様

質問のコメント欄でコメントの行末にスペースを2個入れても改行が追加されない。  
ヘルプによると改行が追加されるように思われる。  
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#linebreaks

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

通常のマークダウン（質問、回答、タグwiki、等）ではサポートをしていますが、コメントでは改行はサポートをしていません。

コメントに改行をサポートしたら、画面のスペースを大幅取ってしまい、質問や回答中心の気をそらせます。

Comment: 仕様としてコメントには改行を入れることができないということですね。わかりました。