# 回答に対するコメントで改行するには

Tags: サポート, コメント

Stack Overflowの回答に対してコメントする場合、改行はどのようにしたら良いのでしょうか。
[stackoverflowで改行入力どうするの？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332/stackoverflow%E3%81%A7%E6%94%B9%E8%A1%8C%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE)によると「スペース２つ空ける、
あるいは`</br>`を入れる」ことにより改行できるようなのですが、うまくいきません。
ご教示のほど、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 重複候補: [コメントで行末にスペースを2個入れても改行が追加されない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260/3060)

Answer (score 6):

コメントで改行はできません。もしコメントで改行したいほどの長い内容を書こうとなさっているのであれば、それはおそらくコメント機能の想定されている使い方ではない方向に向かおうとされています。

コメントは投稿に対する「ふせん」のようなものです。ちょっとした指摘をするのに使ったり、投稿をより具体的にするお願いをするのに使ったりするもので、最終的には消えても構わないくらいのものです。

コメントで長い議論がしたくなった場合、[チャット](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=ja.stackoverflow.com)を使ってください。時には議論が複雑になって頻繁なやり取りをしたくなることがあります。この場合コメントからチャットに場所を移し、話がまとまった後で内容を質問や回答にフィードバックするとうまくいきやすいです。

コメントにコードを書きたくなった場合、インラインコードを使ってください。複数行必要な場合、それはおそらく質問に追記するべきだったり、新しく質問を投稿するべきだったりします。

より詳しくはこちらに説明があります: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: 詳しい説明を読んでみました。コメントは「質問または回答に残される一時的な「付箋」のメモです」という位置づけのようですね。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 3):

参照している記事は「質問」や「回答」の「記事」部分に関する記述でしょう。

そして質問が2014年12月3日であり、現在の日本語版では行末に半角空白2文字は無くても改行できます。
なお英語版では参照記事の仕様は現在も継続して適用されていて、意図的な改行のためには行末に半角空白2文字が必要です。

そしてコメント欄では意図的に改行は出来なさそうです。
ヘルプ記事は以下にあり、コメントの書式設定記事の後ろの方に「改行」についての記述がありますが、それは「以下の完全なヘルプ」の部分であり、コメントに適用されるのは黄色いバックグラウンドで囲われた範囲だけでしょう。
[どこでもコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

> コメントの方法は?
> コメントは[Markdown のごく一部](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)をサポートするため、`_italic_` や `**bold**`、`[named hyperlinks](http://example.com)` などが可能です。

上記`Markdown のごく一部`のリンク先の内容がこれ。

[コメントの書式設定 - Markdown ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

> コメントの書式設定
> コメントで使用できるのは、太字、斜体、コード、リンクだけですが、ごく一部の簡単リンクも使用できます。

上記タイトルを含む黄色いバックグラウンドで囲まれた部分だけがコメントで使える書式設定でしょう。
そしてその直後に以下の記述があります。

> 上記のセクションは、参照の便宜を図るために、編集に関する以下の完全なヘルプから引用しています。

「上記のセクションは、...」が書かれた以後に以下の改行の記述がありますが、「以下の完全なヘルプ」の部分であって「コメント」には適用されないでしょう。

> 改行
> 行末にスペースを 2 個入れると、`<br/>` 改行が追加されます:
>
> ```
> どのようにあなたを愛しているか   
> 私に数えさせてください
> ```

注：引用元のヘルプ記事ではスペース2個が少し黒くなっているが私にはここでは適用方法不明なのでこのままとします。

Comment: 改行できない立て付けのようですね。その変わりに、太字、斜体などを使用して、読みやすいよう工夫する必要がありそうです。ありがとうございます。